# Can't get IP from DHCP on MacPro

Tags: cisco, dhcp, local-area-network, mac, wlan

In little office, with 4 people, I'm setting a LAN with these equipment :

```
NAS
Printers
Router cisco RV130W
4 Macintosh Pro
1 Windows 10 laptop
Internet modem
```

When the Mac are on modem network, DHCP works well, on LAN and WLAN. Cisco router is connected behind the internet modem. When the Mac are on Cisco network there are some troubles : - the Mac cannot get any IP address from DHCP server on LAN ethernet but the Windows laptop can. - the Mac can get IP address from DHCP server on WLAN and windows too.

When I set a static address on Mac (on eth interface) it cannot access to LAN. When I do a ping to gateway, it doesn't work, I have this message "No route to host".

There is no route configuration specific to this network when I type : netstat -nr

I really don't understand what it happen. If you have any ideas ...